# How to assert the page title using page object pattern Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, mstest

I'm using the Page Object Pattern with Selenium C# and MSTest, I'd like to assert that I've arrived at the correct page by asserting the expected page title with the actual page title. I've got the following code but it doesn't work:

Framework:

```
public class MyAccountPage
{
public const string MyAccountPageTitle = "My Account";

public static bool IsAt()
{
return Driver.Instance.Title == MyAccountPageTitle;
}
```

Test:

```
Assert.IsTrue(MyAccountPage.IsAt);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`IsAt` is a *method* - call it:

```
Assert.IsTrue(MyAccountPage.IsAt());
```